# How to clear all checkbox When checkbox id="checkAll" are checked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

How to clear all checkbox When checkbox `id="checkAll"` are checked ?

in my demo , when user checked checkbox `id="checkAll"` all checkbox are checked

But i want to apply to , when user checked checkbox `id="checkAll"` all checkbox are clear , How can i do ?

http://jsfiddle.net/peap/sydzL8Lc/1/

```
$('#checkAll').click(function () {    
     $('input:checkbox').prop('checked', this.checked);       
 });
```

Comment: The fiddle seems to work correctly. How is it not working for you?

Comment: When i checked `Check All` i want to clear all checkbox

Comment: That seems counter-intuitive to me. It's better like it is now.

Comment: what do you mean `clear`? is it `uncheck`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just apply the negation of `this.checked`

```
$('#checkAll').change(function () {    
     $('input:checkbox').not(this).prop('checked', !this.checked);       
 });
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/sydzL8Lc/5/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `change()` function and it you can check by using `this.checked` inside the change event, it will return `boolean` value for checkbox checked status :

### Check All on Main Checked:

```
$('#checkAll').change(function () {    
   $('input:checkbox').prop('checked', this.checked); // all checked on check of #checkAll 
 });
```

### Uncheck All on Main Checked:

```
$('#checkAll').change(function () {    
    $('input:checkbox').prop('checked', !this.checked);   // all unchecked on check of #checkAll
     });
```

if you want all unchecked but no the main check box then:

### Uncheck All Excluding the Main:

```
$('#checkAll').change(function () {    
    $('input:checkbox').not(this).prop('checked', !this.checked);   // all unchecked on check of #checkAll but not itself
         });
```

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding you correctly, you want to clear all the items when they click "Check All" - you might want to change the name to "Clear All" for clarity.

If so, just add a simple ! in front of this.checked

> $('#checkAll').click(function () {
>       $('input:checkbox').prop('checked', !this.checked);
>   });

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use the same ID for multiple elements, since IDs are unique. Instead use `class="checkedItem"`.

If you want to clear all use

```
$('#checkAll').click(function () {    
    $('input:checkbox').prop('checked', !this.checked);       
});
```

However this also clears the first checkbox. To prevent this use

```
$('#checkAll').click(function () {    
    $('input:checkbox').not(this).prop('checked', !this.checked);       
});
```