# How to Clear checkbox When checked other checbox ? using java script

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

How to Clear checkbox When checked other checbox ? using java script

When user checked checkbox `id="checkItem1"` or `id="checkItem2"` or `id="checkItem3"` i want to clear checkbox `id="checkAll"` How can i do that ? using java script

```
<input type="checkbox" id="checkAll" checked > Check All
    <hr />
    <input type="checkbox" id="checkItem1"> Item 1
    <input type="checkbox" id="checkItem2"> Item 2 
    <input type="checkbox" id="checkItem3"> Item 3
```

http://jsfiddle.net/peap/sydzL8Lc/8/

Comment: Didn't you just ask this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25812750/how-to-clear-all-checkbox-when-checkbox-id-checkall-are-checked

Comment: Well, it looks like the question is slightly different, doesn't it?

Comment: Here is [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Regent3000/sydzL8Lc/9/).

Comment: That's called a radiobutton.  What's next, re-inventing the wheel? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using jQuery, you can just write:

```
$("#checkItem1").click(function() {
    $("#checkAll").prop('checked', false);
});
```

and repeat that for `checkItem2` and `checkItem3`. But I recommend to add a class to all `checkItem`s, that would make it easier to select them.